# using mstage() in R to draw stratified samples

Tags: r, sampling, multistage

I trying to use the mstage() function in R to draw a multi-stage stratified sample and don't know how to. I wonder if anyone can help?

The data is in the end.

What I want to achieve is:

At the first stage, draw a stratified sample (stratified by A/B/C in the "group" column). Let's say we randomly draw

- 10 records that belong to group A,
- 20 from group B, and
- 30 from group C.

At the second stage, do another stratified sample but only within the selected records. Let's say we randomly draw:

- 5 from the 10 selected records in A
- 10 from the 20 selected records in B, and
- 15 from the 30 selected records in C.

Given the data below and what I want to achieve, how would you complete this mstage() function call in the end? I am assuming it can be done via mstage() but do let me know if it is not the case!

```
library(sampling)
library(data.table)

set.seed(345092123)

data_sample_frame <- 
  data.table(group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 
                            500, 
                            prob = c(1, 2, 3),
                            replace = T))

data_sample_frame[, id := 1:.N]


setorder(data_sample_frame, group)

set.seed(2340598)

mstage(data_sample_frame,
       stage = list("stratified", ??, ??),
       varnames = list("group", ??, ??),
       size = list(size1 = table(data_sample_frame$group),
                   size2 = c(10, 20, 30),
                   size3 = ??),
       method = list("", ??, ??))
```

I know I can use two strata() calls separately to solve my question but just wonder if mstage() can do both stages in one go.

Comment: It seems that the `mstage` function won't let you do multi-stage sampling where the first two stages are both stratified. I'm not sure if that's a bug or not, but I've never seen a sampling design like that before. Usually, one would do a stratified cluster sampling at the first two stages.

Comment: Good to confirm that it is `mstage` that doesn't allow such a sampling design. 

Re. your comment on this two-stage stratified sampling design, it is being used in practice. Survey organisations don't put all the people drawn at the first stage into the fieldwork. Instead, at the second stage, the sample drawn at the first stage is randomly split into (1) original issues and (2) reserves, and only the original issues are used in the fieldwork. Reserves are only added to fieldwork when unexpected situations happen (e.g., response rate is remarkably lower than expectation).